# Transforming JSON based on inputs and outputs

Tags: javascript, json

Following is an object array that has a value `v`, its input `i` and output `o`.

```js
var data = [
    {
      v: 1,
      i: [],
      o: [1, 2, 3]
    }, 
    {
      v: 2,
      i: [2],
      o: [4, 5, 6]
      ]
    },
    {
      v: 3,
      i: [1, 4],
      o: [7, 8]
    }, 
    {
      v: 4,
      i: [],
      o: [3]
    }
]
```

The final JSON structure is created by checking the input and outputs of each `v`, i.e. the parent child relations...

Final JSON structure..

```
[
    {
        v: 1,
        children: [
            {
                v: 2
            },
            {
                v: 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        v: 4
    }
]
```

I tried by the following code, but it's not transforming the object array properly...

```js
function checkForOutputs(outputs, groupedValueChainEntityLists) {
  for (var i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < groupedValueChainEntityLists[j].inputs.length; j++) {
      var val_Chain = groupedValueChainEntityLists[j].inputs.map((item) => {
        if (outputs[i].o === item.o) {
          return groupedValueChainEntityLists[j];
        }
      });
      return val_Chain;
    }
  }
}


function constructValueChainRelations(data) {
  var valueChainArray = new Array();
  var result = data.map((item) => {
    if (item.i.length === 0) {
      valueChainArray.push(item);
      return checkForOutputs(item.o, data);
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: What is with `o: [7,8]`? where is `v:8`?

Comment: JSON !== JavaScript Object; JSON is (JavaScript Object Notation) which is a representation of an Object-Array-Value structure.

Comment: Also, you have a stray `]` in your 2nd vertex...

Comment: it's not clear to me how the expected json structure matches the object array.

Comment: I just formatted your code. There is a misplaced `]` at the end of the second object in the array. Can you confirm that that is a typo (and remove it if it is)?

Comment: Try lodash .flatten libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some loops and a look up mechanism with `this`.

```js
var data = [{ v: 1, i: [], o: [1, 2, 3] }, { v: 2, i: [2], o: [4, 5, 6] }, { v: 3, i: [1, 4], o: [7, 8] }, { v: 4, i: [], o: [3] }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.v]) {
        this[a.v] = { v: a.v, children: [] };
        result.push(this[a.v]);
    }
    a.o.forEach(function (b) {
        var k = a.v + '|' + b;
        if (a.v !== b && !this[k]) {
            this[k] = { v: b };
            this[a.v].children.push(this[k]);
        }
    }, this);
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are making this too difficult. Simply map the values.

```js
var data = [{
  v: 1,
  i: [],
  o: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
  v: 2,
  i: [2],
  o: [4, 5, 6]
}, {
  v: 3,
  i: [1, 4],
  o: [7, 8]
}, {
  v: 4,
  i: [],
  o: [3]
}];

function transform(verticies, idProp, childProp) {
  return verticies.map(function(vertex) {
    return {
      v: vertex[idProp],
      children: vertex[childProp].filter(function(childVertex) {
        return childVertex !== vertex[idProp];
      }).map(function(childVertex) {
        return {
          v: childVertex
        };
      })
    }
  });
}

var transformed = transform(data, 'v', 'o');
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(transformed, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

#### Result

```
[{
    "v": 1,
    "children": [{
        "v": 2
    }, {
        "v": 3
    }]
}, {
    "v": 2,
    "children": [{
        "v": 4
    }, {
        "v": 5
    }, {
        "v": 6
    }]
}, {
    "v": 3,
    "children": [{
        "v": 7
    }, {
        "v": 8
    }]
}, {
    "v": 4,
    "children": [{
        "v": 3
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that is working..
 **Sample Code**

```
 function populateChildrenRecursively(outputTypeId, valueChainEntities, parentValueChainEntity) {
        for (var i = 0; i < valueChainEntities.length; i++) {
            if (valueChainEntities[i].valueChainEntity.valueChainEntityId != parentValueChainEntity.valueChainEntity.valueChainEntityId && hasInput(outputTypeId, valueChainEntities[i].inputs)) {
                parentValueChainEntity.valueChainEntity.items.push(valueChainEntities[i]);
                if (valueChainEntities[i].outputs.length > 0) {
                    valueChainEntities[i].valueChainEntity.items = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < valueChainEntities[i].outputs.length; j++) {
                        populateChildrenRecursively(valueChainEntities[i].outputs[j].outputTypeId, valueChainEntities, valueChainEntities[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[JSON Conversion](https://plnkr.co/edit/d2wtXcaU37quthBjgrCu?p=preview)